# Laravel Forge Scheduler - Run Command

Tags: laravel, devops, laravel-forge

When using Laravel Forge's scheduler, you can trigger all the cronjob by e.g. running:

```
php /home/forge/default/artisan schedule:run
```

However, when wanting to execute a sole command, it will fail and says "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git".

Via SSH, I would execute the command like this:

```
ssh to the server
cd path/
php artisan command:name
```

So how would I declare it in Laravel Forge's scheduler?

```
php /home/forge/default/artisan command:name
```

Does not work.

Comment: `/default/` should be the folder name - I suspect not yours is not 'default' either. [Here is a piece of tutorial](https://serversforhackers.com/scaling-laravel/forge/forge-cron-server)

Comment: @senty so rather php /home/forge/default command:name? Or should it be php /home/forge/default artisan command:name (without the /)?

Comment: `php /home/forge/your_folder_name/artisan command:name`

Comment: @senty I don't want to run the scheduler but a specific command - that's why I posted this question. Running the scheduler for the cronjob work.

Comment: Yes, it's same approach. Fixed my previous comment

Comment: @senty but this leads to this message: "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" - which is weird as the "schedule:run" gives no error message but the command does.

Comment: Wait - don't you need to utilize scheduler even to run only 1 job with a logic (for example, once a day ie `->daily()`)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190233/discussion-between-james-and-senty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simply to remove the slash after `/path/artisan` - it is `/path` artisan.